# can't access value of ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why can i not access the value of emailia?
It returns undefined :(
Why that?
At "nachricht" it returns the right value.
I did it with emailia the same way.
Have a look at the function   $scope.nachrichtSenden = function(anzeige).

```
angular.module('app', []).controller("MainController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.anzeigen = [];
    $scope.anzeigenGefiltert = [];
    $scope.man = true;
    $scope.woman = true;
    $scope.liebe = 'Test';
    $scope.liebeId = -2;
    $scope.email;

    $scope.getAnzeigen = function() {
        $http.get('getAnzeigen').success(function(data) {
            $scope.anzeigen = data;

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $scope.anzeigen[i].geburtsdatum = moment($scope.anzeigen[i].geburtsdatum.date).locale("de").format('LL');
            }

            console.log($scope.anzeigen);
        });
    };

    $scope.nachrichtSenden = function(anzeige) {
        $http.get(
            'nachrichtSenden?id=' +
            anzeige.id +
            "&nachricht=" +
            $scope.nachricht +
            "&email=" +
            $scope.emailia
        ).success(function(data) {
            console.log($scope.tada);
        });
    };

    $scope.getAnzeigen();
});
```

```html
        <div ng-show="$parent.liebe == anzeige.id">
            <h3>Deine Nachricht an {{'{{anzeige.spitzname}}'}}</h3>
            <textarea name="nachricht" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" ng-model="$parent.nachricht"></textarea>
            <input type="text" ng-model="emailia">
            <button type="button" style="float: right;" ng-click="nachrichtSenden(anzeige)" class="btn btn-warning btn-md">
                Senden!
            </button>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a variable  `$scope.email;`

and you are trying to access the variable `$scope.emailia` which is not defined in your code. Hence the undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you do the type mistake as i see in `console.log($scope.tada)`

```
 $scope.nachrichtSenden = function(anzeige){
    $http.get(
      'nachrichtSenden?id=' +
      anzeige.id +
      "&nachricht=" +
      $scope.nachricht +
      "&email=" +
      $scope.emailia 
     ).success(function(data){
          console.log($scope.tada);

     });
  };
```

check your code 
you are write `console.log($scope.tada);`
instead  `console.log($scope.data);`

may be it will work

Comment: sorry, its not the $scope.tada what i need. it is the $scope.emailia which returns undefined